# Remember me style login page ionic framework using local storage

Tags: local-storage, ionic-framework

I am new to ionic and I want to save username and password in local storage and load it the next time the user come to the page if the remember me box is checked.can some one help?

Answer (score 3):

To save the data in local storage

```
 window.localstorage.setItem ("username",$scope.loginData.username);
 window.localStorage.setItem("password", $scope.loginData.password);
```

To retrieve data use

```
 window.localstorage.getItem("username");
 window.localstorage.getItem("password");
```

Now create a deviceready event listener inside `$ionicPlatform.ready` function.

check the sample code

```
$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", function() {
        if (window.localstorage.getItem("username") !== null && window.localstorage.getItem("password") !== null) {
            state.go("afterLogin.html");
        } else {
            state.go("login.html");
        }
    }, false);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

LocalStorage is nothing more than JSON stored in the client. These are just `key value` pairs that can be set and retrieved using the `key`.

Setting a LocalStorage item.

`localStorage.setItem('username', JSON.stringify('THE USERNAME'))`
Use this when the user sets the username and password.

Getting the LocalStorage Item.

`JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('username'))`
Use this in your `Init` function or just setting it to the `$scope` of your MainController.

Using `JSON` methods just ensure no data is lost during transfer.

Answer (score 0):

Create a module:

```js
    angular.module('ionic.utils', [])

.factory('$localstorage', ['$window', function($window) {
  return {
 set: function(key, value) {
   $window.localStorage[key] = value;
 },
 get: function(key, defaultValue) {
   return $window.localStorage[key] || defaultValue;
 },
 setObject: function(key, value) {
   $window.localStorage[key] = JSON.stringify(value);
 },
 getObject: function(key) {
   return JSON.parse($window.localStorage[key] || '{}');
 }
  }
}]);
```

Then in your app:

```js
 function( $rootScope, $http, $q, Common, $localstorage, UserAuth, Device, DeviceService, $timeout ) {
   return myfunction = function(myvar){
        $localstorage.set('key', myvar);
        var localvar = $localstorage.get('key');
   }
})
```